# representing triplet data set with color on 2d plot

Tags: plotting

I have a huge list of data in the form of triplets numbers (e.g. {x,y,z}) and I want 2d plot. In which I want to plot y vs x on which values of z should be shown with color depending on the value of z for each x,y point. Means variation of z with color on x,y plot. Is it possible to show plot legend outside the plot boundaries?

Please give me suggestions

Comment: Some suggestions: `ListDensityPlot`, `ListPlot`, `Graphics/Point`

Answer (score 2):

The Simplest way is to use `Graphics` and put the points.

```
dat = Table[{x, Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0., 4 \[Pi], \[Pi]/10.}]; (*trial data set*)
(*column 1 and 2 is for data and 3 is for colour*)

ndata = Length[dat];
min = Min[dat[[All, 3]]];max = Max[dat[[All, 3]]];
col = (dat[[All, 3]] - min)/(max - min);
(*to scale the colour index between 0 and 1*)

Graphics[Table[{ColorData["NeonColors"][col[[i]]], PointSize -> Large,
Point[{dat[[i, 1]], dat[[i, 2]]}]}, {i, 1, ndata}], Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> .5]
```

### Simplified Version [courtesy Anon and  belisarius]

```
col = Rescale[dat[[All, 3]]]; pts = dat[[All, 1 ;; 2]];
Graphics[Table[{ColorData["NeonColors"][col[[i]]], PointSize -> Large,
Point[pts[[i]]]}, {i, ndata}], Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> .5]
```

### For drawing with Line

```
Graphics[Table[{ColorData["NeonColors"][col[[i]]], Thick,
Line[{pts[[i]], pts[[i + 1]]}]}, {i, ndata - 1}], Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> .5]
```

[image: color]
[image: plot]

### Using ColorScheme as legend

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
(*create legendbox*)
legend = Graphics[Legend[ColorData["NeonColors"][1 - #1] &, 10, " Max", " Min", 
LegendShadow -> None, LegendBorder -> Automatic]];

(*put it in inset*)
lps = {11.0, .5}; (*legend position*)
Graphics[{Table[{ColorData["NeonColors"][col[[i]]], Thick, 
Line[{pts[[i]], pts[[i + 1]]}]}, {i, ndata - 1}], 
Inset[legend, lps, Automatic, {1, 1}]},
Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> .5, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: legend]

Comment: Take a look at `Rescale[]`

Comment: I was just about to say that, (1) `col = Rescale[dat[[All, 3]]];`, (2) `pts = dat[[All, 1 ;; 2]];` simplifies the `Point` to `Point[pts[[i]]]` and (3) `{i, 1, ndata}` is equivalent to `{i,ndata}`. But nice answer, +1.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions but if i want join all my points then how can i include this in your given code

Comment: well @physicist, then you can chose two points at a time and use `Line`.

Comment: How can i reverse the order of colors in this scheme in the code

Comment: @physicist, the first way I can think about is to use `1-col[[i]]` instead of `col[[i]]` with `ColorData["ColorScheme"]`.

Comment: Is possible to put color bar for same, outside the plot like showed in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32844/need-4d-plot-3d-color-for-function for 4d data. But I need for 3d data with third axis represented by color.