# 2D Plotting of triplet data set with third axis as variation of thickness of curve

Tags: plotting

I have similar question like mentioned at [representing triplet data set with color on 2d plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28016/representing-triplet-data-set-with-color-on-2d-plot) but this time instead of color I need to represent variation of third axis with the thickness of the curve

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28202/5478)

Answer (score 1):

Here `Filling` can be a big help.

Some sample data:

```
data = {#, Sin[#], #^2} & /@ Range[0, 10, 1/4];
```

A function to help create the variable "thickness".  The parameter `f` is like a scaling factor:

```
addThickness[data_, f_] := 
 Transpose[
  data /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {{x, y}, {x, y - f z}, {x, y + f z}}]
```

and now make the `FillingStyle` match the `PlotStyle`:

```
ListLinePlot[addThickness[data, 0.01], 
 Filling -> {2 -> {1}, 3 -> {1}}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
 FillingStyle -> Opacity[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: How can I apply this method to list data like data = Table[{TL[[jj, 5]], TL[[jj, 6]], TL[[jj, 1]]}, {jj, 1, 
    Length[TL]}];

Comment: I have used the above code but it is not so useful because it is creating negative values of third variable which is not the part of data